# формат даты при запросе

Tags: php, mysql, sql, битрикс

Мне необходимо при запросе фильтром указать определенную дату, но в объекте который я получаю дата такого типа:

```
 #value: DateTime @1661367600 {#3712 ▼
        date: 2022-08-25 00:00:00.0 Asia/Yekaterinburg (+05:00)
      }
```

Но при этом значение, которое я передаю в фильтр просто строка типа: '25.08.2022',
как отформатировать данную дату, чтобы фильтр запроса работал?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php, чтобы преобразовать строку в дату, а затем используйте http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, чтобы получить дату в нужном формате

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от того, где вы используете фильтр запроса. Если строите строку SQL вручную, то вам помогут эти функции: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/general/date_time.php
А если используете ORM, то в запросах как раз нужно использовать объекты DateTime: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=05748&LESSON_PATH=3913.3516.5748